# Routing trought site-to-site tunnel

Tags: routes, vpn

I have 3 routers, two of them (A and B) are connected locally to network 192.168.0.0/24,
router A has his own network 192.168.13.0/24, to which Router B has a working static routing.
Router C is connected to router B trought a IPSec Site-to-site tunnel and also has it's own network (192.168.100.0/24).
Network 192.168.0.0/24 has access to 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.13.0/24
Network 192.168.100.0/24 has only access to 192.168.0.0/24
Network 192.168.13.0/24 has only access to 192.168.0.0/24

My problem is that 192.168.100.0/24 can't access 192.168.13.0 and vice versa
Here is a link to a basic diagram how it looks: https://postimg.cc/ykQYJxKC

Router A is MikroTik, B and C are Vigor 3900 series.

I tried to setup Multiple IPSec SA, but the post i see only show examples with two router or where all te subnets are connected to at least one of the VPN routers, which is my problem because network 192.168.13.0/24 isn't on any of the site-to-site routers (B,C)

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Maybe a better fit on [su] or [sf] - just read the guidelines there first.